# No default argument in constructor with default arguments all in a 2D List

Tags: python

My current code:

**WormModScratch.py**

```
class WormMod:
    def __init__(self,wormColor, appleOrangeBananaPos = [[-1,-1],[0,0],[3,4]]):
        self.currentWormColor = wormColor
        self.appleOrangeBananaPos = appleOrangeBananaPos

    def say_hi(self):
        print(self.appleOrangeBananaPos[0][0])
        print(self.appleOrangeBananaPos[0][1])
        print(self.appleOrangeBananaPos[1][0])
        print(self.appleOrangeBananaPos[2][0])
        print(self.appleOrangeBananaPos[2][1])
        # print(self.orangePos[0], self.orangePos[1])

    def getHighScore(self):
        highscore_file = open("highscore.txt", "r")
        scorelist = highscore_file.readlines()
        highscore_file.close()
        return scorelist
```

**test2.py**

```
from WormModScratch import WormMod

z = WormMod("blue")
z.say_hi()

print(z.getHighScore())
```

**Output**

```
-1
-1
0
3
4
['100\n', '50\n', '25\n']

------------------
(program exited with code: 0)
Press return to continue
```

**My question:**

```
def __init__(self,wormColor, appleOrangeBananaPos = [[-1,-1],[0,0],[3,4]]):
```

and

```
z = WormMod("blue")
```

I want to have the first element in my 2dList undefaulted like 
`[2],[0,0],[3,4]` I want to make it so WormMod must include two apple x y values while the other two fruits are defaulted to `0,0` and `3,4`.

```
z = WormMod("blue",[applex,appley])
```

How do I accomplish two undefaulted values and four defaulted values as described above? This is only my 3rd week in python and am still learning.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the function, you could split the 2d array into 3 lists, or never join them in the first place. Then, inside the function if you need them to be joined you could easily just join them all together again, thereby allowing you to set 2 of them with defaults and leave one as a requirement.